# Python - TypedDict type hint keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeddict

I have 2 classes. One that inherits TypedDict class in which I have set of keys that should accept certain type of data:

```
class UserType(TypeDict):
   first_name: str
   last_name: str
   age: int
```

In another class `Customer`, I am using `UserType` dict for storing the information of the customer and have a method to update the information:

```
class Customer:
   def __init__():
     self._userInfo: UserType = {
       "first_name": "John",
       "last_name": "John",
       "age": 27
    }
    
    def set_info(key: str, val: Any):
      self._userInfo[key] = val
```

In `set_info` I want to type hint `key` to show only keys that are defined in `UserType` like:

```
customer = Customer()
customer.set_info(SHOULD HINT KEY HERE (first_name, ...), "Somedata")
```

dict. I tried something like:

```
def set_info(key: UserType, val: Any):
   ...
```

But this didn't work. I guess, I am trying to use it as interfaces as I am coming from strict typed language background. Any idea how this can be achieved? I am flexible to change it something different other than a `dict`

Comment: Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68733562/how-to-type-hint-a-getter-to-only-allow-keys-of-dict) helps.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I came across this, but here, he is using Literal. That means I need to defined the keys twice everytime and have to use 2 separate class / literals wherever I need to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TypedDict` doesn't expose its keys as a distinct type, nor is there really a good way to define such a type.

**Not recommended**

Some people use `typing.Literal`, but that is intended for, well, *literals*. Use `key: Literal["first_name", "last_name", "age"]` allows `c.set_info("first_name", "bob")`, but not `k = "first_name"; c.set_info(k, "bob")`, because `k` is not a literal. **I don't recommend doing this**, but I felt it needed to be addressed.

**Better**

Another alternative would be to explicitly define a separate enumerate type and use its members, rather than raw keys, as arguments.

```
class CustomerKey(enum.StrEnum):
    FIRST_NAME = "first_name"
    LAST_NAME = "last_name"
    AGE = "age"

# This could (somewhat awkwardly) also be defined as
#
#   CustomerKey = enum.StrEnum(dict(zip(map(str.upper, UserType.__annotation__),
#                                       UserType.__annotation__)))
#
# to avoid repetition of the exact keys.


class Customer:
    ...

    def set_info(key: CustomerKey, val: Any):     
        self._userInfo[key] = val
```

**Better still**

This is assuming you don't have a good reason to store the attributes separately, and only use the `TypedDict` as the argument to a class method, for example,

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class Customer:
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    age: int

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d: UserType):
        return cls(**d)
```

---

**Best (hypothetical)**

Don't read too much into what follows. I'm mostly thinking out loud about ways that `TypeDict` could expose the information it contains as type hints.

In an ideal world, the keys of a `TypedDict` would themselves form a type. Then perhaps you could write something like

```
class Customer:
    ...

    def set_info(key: UserType.keys, val: Any):
        ...
```

Even better, there would also be a way to tied the value assigned to `key` to a type that could be used to annotate `val`, so that if `key == "first_name"`, then `val` must have type `str. I imagine this would require some mix of dependent types (where types can depend on value), singleton types (where for every value there is an associated type that contains *only* that value) and generics. Something vaguely like

```
    def set_info(key: UserType.keys, val: UserType[key])
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and alternative solution. Much appreciated